# Is there a way to change the inline HTML code in my XLS form to make the image responsive?

Tags: html, forms, xls

How can I change the inline html so that the image is responsive? This is within an XLS form, so I am very limited here, I think.

What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

The code:

```html
<p>
  <span style="font-size:16px; color:rgb(50, 54, 58);">SOME TEXT</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>
    <img alt="Info" src="myimage.jpg" >
  </span>
</p>
<p>
  <span style="font-size:16px; color:rgb(50, 54, 58);">MORE TEXT</span>
</p>
```

ESRI provides a list of accepted html tags, but I am not advanced enough to understand how this helps me: [image]

I have tried playing with the width tag, but it's not doing anything responsive.

Comment: What is _inline HTML_? Did you mean _inline CSS_? Yes, you can: `width: 100%`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: OP's table seems to [be similar content-wise to this one](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/create-surveys/styleyourform.htm) (it's organized a bit different), which might help in answering the question. It might be possible to add `style="max-width:100%; height:auto"` to `<img>`.

Comment: hi @RickN, I tried `<img style="max-width:100%; height:auto" alt="Info" src="myimage.png">`, to no avail.

Comment: @Justinas, could you elaborate a bit? I have never used inline CSS, and no changes I make are impacting the page. Unfortunately I cannot use the web inspector to play as this is in a XLSForm/interface. Do you mean `<img alt="Info" src="myimage.png" style= "width:100%">`

Comment: @Anna1 Yes, I mean that.

Comment: @Justinas hmm, unfortunately that didn't change anything...